# C# System.UnauthorizedAccessException I cant modify or do nothing with files

Tags: c#, file, exception, permissions

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMv2P.png)

I have worked with files before and never happend this to me.

Framework 4.7.2

The main appliccation is a form appliccation.
The problem persist with different files and different locations.

I have tried:

- Rus VS as Administrator.
- Give full access permission for all to files.
- Set excecution level in app.manifest to Administrator. (Current and main appliccation)
- See if the file have read-only unchecked
- Do the files things in the main proyect
- Try other files and other directories (Don't work)

Any idea?

Comment: Are user, under which account application starts, is a owner of the file? And could this user just open this file with notepad or other app?

Comment: Is the read-only box checked on the file?

Comment: the files are in mi computer, i am admin and yes i can open it

Comment: no read-only problem

Comment: Is the file in use?  Does the problem happen if you try a different file in a different folder?

Comment: @TawabWakil The problem persist with different files and different locations.

Comment: Assuming it's a Windows computer, I don't know what else it could be besides permissions.  Either your permissions or the account under which the app is running.  I am able to run your code on my computer with no problem to update an Excel file.

Comment: @TawabWakil Solved! Thanks for the help! was the antivirus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:(After 2 hours) the antivirus had blocked my application without telling me...